# Tokenizing a custom text file format file using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, tokenize

I want to parse a text-based file format that has a slightly quirky syntax. Here's a few valid example lines:

```
<region>sample=piano C3.wav key=48 ampeg_release=0.7 // a comment here
<region>key = 49 sample = piano Db3.wav
<region>
group=1
key = 48
    sample = piano D3.ogg
```

I think it would be too complicated for me to come up with a regular expression that makes sense of that, but I am wondering if there is a good way of tokenising this type of input without writing my own parser? i.e  I would like something that reads the above input and spits out a stream of 'tokens', for example, the output for the start of my example format would be something like:

```
new Region(), new Sample("piano C3.wav"), new Key("48"), new AmpegRelease("0.7"), new Region()
```

Is there a good library / tutorial that would point me in the right direction for an elegant way to implement this?

**Update:** I tried this with [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com), but the quirks of the syntax I need to parse (in particular the fact that the data following sample= can have a space in it) led them to suggest that I might be better of writing my own code based on String.Split. See discussion [here](http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/256803).

Comment: Is this fileformat sfz? Hard to google, please mention it if it is

Comment: yes, format is [here](http://www.cakewalk.com/DevXchange/article.aspx?aid=108), but I am generally interested in the best approach to this type of problem irrespective of the specifics of sfz

Answer (score 2):

For this type of thing I'd get the lightweight but robust [CoCo/R](http://ssw.jku.at/Coco/#CS). If you show me some more sample input, I might come up with a grammar starting point.

---

> I've used lex and yacc before, so I have some parsing experience. – Mark Heath 17 mins ago

Well you're in luck: I've found a lex grammar for `sfz` in Fedora's soundfont-utils package. That package contains the [sfz2pat util](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sfz2pat). You can get the (source) package here:

> http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/14/i386/soundfont-utils-0.4-10.fc12.i686.html 
>      ([src.rpm](http://hany.sk/mirror/fedora/releases/14/Everything/source/SRPMS/gt-0.4-10.fc12.src.rpm))

According to a quick probe the latest version of the grammar is from november 2004 but quite elaborate (58k in sfz2pat.l). Here is a sample to get a taste:

```
%option noyywrap
%option nounput
%option outfile = "sfz2pat.c"

nm  ([^\n]+".wav"|[^ \t\n\r]+|\"[^\"\n]+\")
ipn [A-Ga-g][#b]?([0-9]|"-1")

%s  K

%%

"//".*  ;

<K>"<group>"    {
    int i;
    leave_region();
    leave_group();
    if (!enter_group()) {
        SFZERR
        "Can't start group\n");
        return 1;
    }
    am_in_group_scope = TRUE;
    for (i = FIRST_SFZ_PARM; i < MAX_SFZ_PARM; i++) group_parm[i] = default_parm[i];
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_FLOAT_PARM; i++) group_flt_parm[i] = default_flt_parm[i];
    group_parm[REGION_IN_GROUP] = current_group;
    BEGIN(0);
}
<K>"<region>"   {
    int i;
    if (!am_in_group) {
        SFZERR
        "Can't start region outside group.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    leave_region();
    if (!enter_region()) {
        SFZERR
        "Can't start region\n");
        return 1;
    }
    am_in_group_scope = FALSE;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SFZ_PARM; i++) region_parm[i] = group_parm[i];
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_FLOAT_PARM; i++) region_flt_parm[i] = group_flt_parm[i];
    BEGIN(0);
}
<K>"sample="{nm} {
    int i = 7, j;
    unsigned namelen;
    if (yytext[i] == '"') {
        i++;
        for (j = i; j < yyleng && yytext[j] != '"'; j++) ;
    }
    else j = yyleng;
    namelen = (unsigned)(j - i + 1);
    sfzname = strncpy( (char *)malloc(namelen), yytext+i, (unsigned)(j-i) );
    sfzname[j-i] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < (int)namelen; i++) if (sfzname[i] == '\\') sfzname[i] = '/';
    SFZDBG
    "Sample name is \"%s\"", sfzname);
    SFZNL
    if (read_sample(sfzname)) {
#ifndef LOADER
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
#endif
        return 0;
    }
    BEGIN(0);
}
[...snip...]
```

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it. The file format spec is [here](http://www.cakewalk.com/DevXchange/article.aspx?aid=108)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the language is fairly regular, I'd recommend writing a quick parser using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  It's got a pretty easy learning curve for someone with parsing experience, and it outputs C# (among other things).

Comment: thanks will try this out. I've used lex and yacc before, so I have some parsing experience.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Gardens Point LEX](http://gplex.codeplex.com/) and [Gardens Point Parser Generator](http://gppg.codeplex.com/) for generating parsers. They work well especially if you have some lex/yacc knowledge.

IMO, these two make the best parser generator for .NET.

One bonus point: the creators respond fast to bug reports and suggestions as can be seen [here](http://gppg.codeplex.com/workitem/8565).